Generating a Debian Snap for a Bazel project
I have a Bazel project that creates a binary, and I would like to publish it using snap.
I'm new to deployment and saw some examples but I couldn't find anything that compiles a Bazel project. Anyone has an idea/example snapcraft.yaml file that compiles a Bazel project?
